# How can I speed up my Xagent?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am creating powerpoints files via Apache Poi in an XPages app.

On an xpage I have a repeat control, each row in the repeat displays a button which initiates an "xagent" that does the job (SSJS).

```
<xp:button id="button7" value="Download">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="norefresh">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.docId = obj.unid;
sessionScope.slideType = "TITLE_AND_CONTENT";
sessionScope.fieldList = ["refName","refSub","refStrength","refWeakness"];
context.redirectToPage("StreamPresentation.xsp");}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

I notice that it takes some time to trigger the export for each row. Here is some "time-reporting" from the log:

```
2016-09-26 16:57:05   HTTP JVM: time:2016-09-26 16:57
2016-09-26 16:57:05   HTTP JVM: docId:6AD84C823BD8A52FC125803A0051BE49
2016-09-26 16:57:38   HTTP JVM: time:2016-09-26 16:57
2016-09-26 16:57:38   HTTP JVM: docId:660E0CC12C3E1046C1258039006AA394
2016-09-26 16:57:58   HTTP JVM: time:2016-09-26 16:57
2016-09-26 16:57:58   HTTP JVM: docId:C8DD8933E26057C3C1258039006A3ED0
```

How can I speed up the process?

My xagent code looks somewhat as followed:

```
importPackage(java.lang);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel);

//getting sessionvariables
var sessSlide = sessionScope.slideType;
var docId = sessionScope.docId;
print("time:" + @Now());
print("docId:" + docId);
var sessFields = sessionScope.fieldList;

var doc:NotesDocument;
doc = database.getDocumentByUNID(docId);

var ppt: XMLSlideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

/* 
* creating slides here...
/*

//The Faces Context global object provides access to the servlet environment via the external content
var extCont = facesContext.getExternalContext();
//The servlet's response object provides control to the response object
var pageResponse = extCont.getResponse();
//Get the output stream to stream binary data
var pageOutput = pageResponse.getOutputStream();

//Set the content type and headers
pageResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
pageResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
pageResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);

ppt.write(pageOutput);
pageOutput.flush();
pageOutput.close();

facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many many factors that determine the all over speed of an application. If you want to get to the bottom of total computation time, you need to look at each operation to get an idea.

There are quite some resources out there, for your convenience

- [AD109 on DeveloperWorks](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/AD109-XPages_Performance_and_Scalability)
- [XPages tuning on Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/MaargaSystems/x-pages-performancefinal)
- [Dalsgaard on performance](https://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/tuning-your-xpages/)
- [The NTF on XPages performance](https://nathantfreeman.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/xpages-performance-pro-tips/)
- [Sven on high performance XPages](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=913)

Back from reading? Here is what I would start looking at:

The first stop would be to move your entire code from SSJS to Java. Each time you call a Java object or Java method in SSJS it gets boxed/unboxed which costs some time. I suspect however that that step alone won't give you much reprieve. But it is a necessary step for more extreme measures.
Once you have a Java class doing your work you can use a regular Java application to test it from the command line and add more timer statements. Or try using a [Java profiler](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/top-5-java-profilers-revealed-real-world-data-with-visualvm-jprofiler-java-mission-control-yourkit-and-custom-tooling/).

Things to look out for:

- How long does it take to navigate to the documents. A view Navigator with `autoupdate=false`is most of the time fastest
- Can you load the data from a view rather than opening a document
- How long does it take to open a document you read
- Do you read documents only once, even if you might need them more often
- Are there inefficient loops
- Are all objects properly recycled
- Do you avoid lengthy string operations (StringBuilder is your friend)
- If the output documents are large a stream approach (similar to Sax) might be faster than a dom approach
- Import only what you need

The performance gremlin might be in the code you didn't show.

Comment: more specific are there figures how long it takes to trigger an xagent after each other? in my case I have an input and an outputstream.

Comment: All factors above influence it. Depends on how busy your server is. You could - using Ajax launch them in parallel - if you don't depend on session variables

Answer (score 1):

I find it a bit confusing: your repeat contains buttons. So user needs to click it to start xagent. So those times (16:57:05, 16:57:38, 16:57:58) are when someone clicked that button. I see nothing slow from code perspective.

UNLESS user clicked all of them in succession, and you observe xagent delayed starts.  THEN the problem is in [synchronization in XPages](https://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/17.07.2011101855KLEBRW.htm).

You can try mentioned `xsp.session.transient` property or [multiple threads](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Threads%20and%20Jobs) to prepare you presentations in advance.